# I get CPU Fan Error when I turn on PC for the first time in the morning, then it works after restart

Tags: fan

I got custom built PC one year ago and I only got CPU Fan Error when I first plugged it in or when there was a power outage, otherwise it booted normally.

After one year I reinstalled Windows on my PC and installed optical disc drive in my case. Every time I turn on the PC I get the CPU Fan Error, then I turn it off and back on and it works fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it.  It’s. It clear what problem your trying to achieve

Comment: Add the complete error message or photo.

Comment: It's almost certainly something in the BIOS settings, assuming the fan is actually working fine.

Answer (score -1):

The CPU fan likely has a speed sensor, and it is not spinning fast enough when it is getting checked.  This might be a sign that your CPU fan is wearing out.  Or it may just take longer than most to get up to speed.  Since the fan is a very important part of your cooling system, I would replace it.

It is also possible that a setting in your BIOS is incorrect.  But most warning levels that I've seen are temperature and voltage levels, not RPMs.